# Is there a way to hide a Folder on the Desktop without '.dot' naming?

Tags: nautilus

I'm wondering if it's possible to hide a folder without renaming it with a dot on the Desktop.

Ubuntu 12.04

Thanks

Comment: I dont think there is, the only way is to start the file name with a dot for example .desktop in a file browser.

Comment: Maby a different file file browser will handle this differently Google something like best Linux file browser

Comment: @markkirby I don't think a new file browser is necessary., or even will integrate well. The best idea right now is to try to use filesystem metadata.

Answer (score 13):

You can create a file called `.hidden` and write the names of the files you want to hide in it.

**BEFORE**

- /home/user/Desktop/file1
- /home/user/Desktop/file2

**CREATE** .hidden file, `echo file1 > /home/user/Desktop/.hidden`

**AFTER**

- /home/user/Desktop/file1  (**HIDDEN**)
- /home/user/Desktop/file2
- /home/user/Desktop/.hidden (**HIDDEN**)

No file got moved nor renamed.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. But the problem is that then you won't be able to see any icon on your desktop, but will be able to see everything in `/home/user/Desktop`.

The trick is fairly simple and straightforward:

- Install `gnome-tweak-tool`:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
  ```
- Run `gnome-tweak-tool` and click on **Desktop** option. Turn "*Have file manager handle the desktop*" to off.
  [image: gnome-tweak-tool disabling icons]

And you're good to go!