# hide offline website folders in Terminal

Tags: command-line, bash

I download many web pages to consult them offline but when i navigate using the terminal it's annoying to have all the html related folders(the folders containing the images, the CSS, the Javascript...) listed.

i use a ".hidden" file to hide these Folder in Nemo as submitted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176135/is-there-a-way-to-hide-a-folder-on-the-desktop-without-dot-naming) but the ".hidden" file will not hide files and directories from a command line listing, such as the output of ls.

is there any way to hide there Folders also in Terminal ?

Comment: I don't think there's a way other than creating lots of aliases for all commands, like `alias ls="ls --hide='*pattern*'"`. It will also work globally, although I imagine if you want it really bad, you could write .bashrc or .zshrc where the set of aliases would depend on the current dir.

Comment: See `man ls`: `-a, --all        do not ignore entries starting with .`